# Adding strings to numbers with different length

Tags: string, matching

I want to have an object like this, matching both of them and putting the names in each ID, both objects have a different length so I tried set names but it didn't work.
Any suggestions?

**First Object**

```
+----+-------+--+
| ID | Test  |  |
+----+-------+--+
|  1 | C     |  |
|  1 | M     |  |
|  1 | C     |  |
|  1 | M     |  |
|  2 | C     |  |
|  2 | M     |  |
|  2 | C     |  |
|  2 | M     |  |
|  4 | C     |  |
|  4 | M     |  |
|  4 | C     |  |
|  4 | M     |  |
+----+-------+--+
```

**Second Object**

```
+-----------+-----+--+
|   Names   | ID  |  |
+-----------+-----+--+
| Pepsi     |   1 |  |
| Coke      |   2 |  |
| Acuarious |   3 |  |
| Fanta     |   4 |  |
| Beer      |   5 |  |
| Fries     |   6 |  |
+-----------+-----+--+

+----+-------+--------+--+
| ID | Names |  Test  |  |
+----+-------+--------+--+
|  1 | Pepsi | C      |  |
|  1 | Pepsi | M      |  |
|  1 | Pepsi | C      |  |
|  1 | Pepsi | M      |  |
|  2 | Coke  | C      |  |
|  2 | Coke  | M      |  |
|  2 | Coke  | C      |  |
|  2 | Coke  | M      |  |
|  4 | Fanta | C      |  |
|  4 | Fanta | M      |  |
|  4 | Fanta | C      |  |
|  4 | Fanta | M      |  |
+----+-------+--------+--+
```

Comment: I hate seeing a hyperlink in your question.  Either post it here or don't.

Comment: Sorry man, It just a picture, it´s easy than writing here. I tried here but the format was wrong. I thought this is a better way. Please take a look.

Comment: Not easier.  You were wrong again.  Not interested.

Comment: @R-guy creating an image is easier than writing that in here?! that's funny!

Comment: @R-guy Last time I checked making an image representing your question took a few more steps than just plain out asking the question...

Comment: Let´s see if all the users think the same way.

Comment: @R-guy Your 4 downvotes in just 10 minutes seem to imply that most, if not all users think the same way...

Comment: Sure...First time here, so I don´t know but it seems someone fixed the problem. Thanks and next time I will do it better.

Answer (score 0):

I think I sorted it out.

a <- merge(firstobject,secondobject,by.x="ID",by.y="ID",all.x=T,all.y=T)

This create a file that match by ID and at the same time put NA for those ones that don´t match.

To get rid off the NAs

a <- a[!is.na(a$ID),]

I hope this helps.!!!